# Laravel error with php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to follow this guide:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on aws. I'm using laravel 5.2. I'm new to laravel (and aws too for that matter), I've done everything in the guide and get this error.

When I run:

> php artisan migrate

I get the following error:

> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'homestead'@'localhost' (usin g password: YES)

The .env file looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local APP_DEBUG=true APP_KEY=hXP0uBJkQos3cHK7D8f6LVx2SLuLAuyv

DB_HOST=localhost 
DB_DATABASE=homestead 
DB_USERNAME=homestead 
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file 
SESSION_DRIVER=file 
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=localhost 
REDIS_PASSWORD=null 
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525 MAIL_USERNAME=null 
MAIL_PASSWORD=null MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Edit: Okay, so I guess this problem was due to a lack of understanding of ubuntu, mysql and laravel. I followed the guide in the link above exactly but I guess it was meant for people running homestead. It looks like on an ubuntu server you have to manually create the database (guess it seems obvious to most).

So login to mysql with:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then enter the password when you are prompted for it.

It's probably not a good idea to use root but I'm just learning so yea.
The password you enter here is the same password you have to enter in the .env file in the laravel root directory.

Once logged into mysql enter:

```
mysql> create database homestead;
```

This creates a database with the same name as the one specified in the .env file DB_DATABASE=homestead. I should probably change it from homestead as I'm not using homestead :/

The DB_USERNAME is the same username that we use to log into mysql so

```
DB_USERNAME = root
```

While the password is the same password we used to log into mysql.

This probably all seems obvious but I'm new and had no idea. It also wasn't covered in the quickstart guide on the laravel website. Maybe I didn't follow it accurately, if so let me know.

Cheers

Comment: did you already install MySQL on AWS?

Comment: I typed mysql --version and got : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: What is DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, Does a database automatically get created with these credentials? Or do I have to do it manually? Is DB_PASSWORD meant to be the password I use to log into mysql? I log into mysql with: "mysql -u root -p"  <Then I enter password>.  Is this password supposed to be the same as DB_PASSWORD?

Comment: mysql -u homestead -p
gives me the same error, how do I give homestead the permission to log into my database?

Comment: Are you able to log in to mysql using `myslq -u root -p`? If you are just run the following SQL `CREATE DATABASE my_db;` where `my_db` is how you want to name your database.

Comment: yup thanks a bunch, I created a database called homestead and it seems to be working. I guess this is the answer. Can you leave an answer, so I can select it as the accepted answer. That way this question doesn't go unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned you, you need to login to MySQL via terminal `mysql -u root -p`, where root is the MySQL user, then input your password, then just create the database using the SQL `CREATE DATABASE my_db;` where `my_db` is the database name and finally just update your .env file with your database and credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you're using a linux machine, but I am mainly adding this for the sake of windows users working on their local machines who might in the future deal with the same issue. (As I have in the past).

**My personal experience with this is that if you can help yourself, ALWAYS create a new user with the necessary privileges and NOT set the the DB_USERNAME the root user.**

Under privileges on your db page on phpMyAdmin user interface, you get a list of all users with both global and database-specific access. The user **sage-admin** has all the privileges to my DB, as shown in the image:
[The list of all users registered with mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRKJI.png)

In your .env file in laravel you add the properties of this user and the targeted database and it just works!

Answer (score -2):

You need to update .env file with correct credentials, for example

```
DB_HOST=localhost 
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
```

to correctly connect with the database. If you have not created the database before, you can create it through PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Laravel is set up to where it uses the .ENV file OR defaults to the database.php file. You should **NEVER** set these in your database.php.

Comment: **NEVER ???** do some research. Laravel never constraint you to not use your own db.

Comment: @OliverQueen is right. You should not edit the values in your database.php file directly as your credentials would end up in your repository. You should always use env variables. You can set them in your .env or in the server env settings. Bold is merited in this case.

Comment: [For more information about this, here is an article I came across.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-environment-variables)